# Is there way to prove something is in NP without a verifier?

Tags: algorithm

There is a theorem that states that if A is polynomially reducible to B and B is in P, then A will be in P.

Now, would that hold for NP problems?

Simply, since coming out with verifiers all the time might be a longer/trickier task if there is a actually an easier way to to prove something is in NP.

Comment: You probably want to ask that type question in the computer science site -> https://cs.stackexchange.com since it's not about programming

Comment: @user3386109 That was a personal assumption. The actual question to awnser is in the title

Comment: If you're asklng "is the only way to prove that something is in NP to reduce it to a known problem in NP" the answer is clearly no. Since there must be at least one problem that's proven to be in NP in a different way, otherwise all the proofs would be circular. More constructively, one can use the definition of NP directly to prove a problem is in NP.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there are two ways to prove that a problem is in NP.

The first would be to describe a non-deterministic polynomial algorithm that solves the problem.

However, this is easier said than done and is why the typical approach to proving a problem is in NP is to use a certificate and a verifier.

Reformulate the problem as a decision problem and show that a yes answer and its certificate (a candidate answer) can be verified in polynomial time.

Reducing problems to other problems is useful for proving whether a problem is NP-Complete. If there is a problem A that is known to be NP-Complete, and we have a problem B that is just known to be in NP and we show that there is a reduction from A to B, then B is proven to be NP-Complete.